# Php text field edit file

Tags: php, html, file, config, textfield

Iv have made a system that allows you to edit a config.php file through a text field on a web page But the textbox shows the whole files contents is there a way I can limit it to only show part of a line like this

```
$paypal_email = "mypaypalemail@gmail.com";
```

and only show

```
mypaypalemail@gmail.com
```

In the text box. Heres my code

```
<?php
$process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
    foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
        unset($process[$key][$k]);
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
            $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
        } else {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
        }
    }
}
unset($process);
?>
<?php

$file = 'config.php';
// print_r( glob( dirname(__FILE__) . "/*.php"  ) );

$configFile = html_entity_decode(file_get_contents($file), ENT_NOQUOTES);

if ( isset( $_POST["save_button"] ) && $_POST["config_changes"]){
$changes = $path = str_replace("\"", "", $_POST["config_changes"]);
  file_put_contents($file, $_POST["config_changes"]);
}
?>

<html>
  <body>
  <center>
  <b>
  <font face="arial" size="3" color="#000000">
  Welcome edit your Options here
  <br>
    <form method="post" action="controlpanel.php">
      <textarea name="config_changes" rows="30" cols="50"><?php echo $configFile ?></textarea>
      <br>
      <button name="save_button">Save</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I consider this unsafe programming, but you probably just need to use a regular expression and PHP preg_match function

Comment: That is really horribly insecure if you ever plan to execute config.php, since it'd be trivial to inject arbitrary code.  I'd suggest using a JSON encoded file or similar instead, and sanitising which keys are allowed to be set from a white list.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was using a regular expression, but I stumbled upon something way better.
The PHP function [token_get_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) to be exact.

You pass the file contents into that function (in this demo, I use some sample code inside token_get_all as a parameter. You can pass the complete file here though.

```
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php $paypal_email = "mypaypalemail@gmail.com"; ?>');

$vars = array();
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if ($token[0] == T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) {
        $vars[] = $token[1];
        continue;
    }
}

var_dump($vars);
```

It should return all variables in that file, like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(25) ""mypaypalemail@gmail.com"" }
```

Use this to debug a little and check which index the variable you are searching for is.
You can then access the variable at the given index.

As mentioned earlier, I don't know what you're using this for, but it sounds unsafe.
I strongly recommend searching for another solution.